# Flutter Upgrade not become complete

Tags: flutter, upgrade

I try to upgrade flutter by command prompt, just type "flutter upgrade" after that this message show. I tried several time but it never become done. Always show fail. Please help anyone. Message of Command prompt are below:

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ee76268252c22f5c11e82a7b87423ca3982e51a7... Downloading the Dart SDK using the BITS service failed, retrying with WebRequest... Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.                       At D:\flutter\bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1:68 char:5                 
+     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dartSdkUrl -OutFile $dartSdkZip                                                           +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                               + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc eption                                                                
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying...

Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ... Checking Dart SDK version... Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ee76268252c22f5c11e82a7b87423ca3982e51a7... Downloading the Dart SDK using the BITS service failed, retrying with WebRequest... Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. At D:\flutter\bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1:68 char:5
+     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dartSdkUrl -OutFile $dartSdkZip
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying...

Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ... Checking Dart SDK version... Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ee76268252c22f5c11e82a7b87423ca3982e51a7.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple
You just need to add the following line to your PATH environment variable.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

https://sharpcode.pro/flutter-doctor-is-not-working/